# My AJAX function keeps getting error as result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new using AJAX or jQuery and I'm trying to insert some data in a table whitout loading another page, I can't tho.

Here is my AJAX func:
Edit:

```
function SumbitAction(act_id) {
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
type: "POST",
url: 'Accion.php',
data: {Action:act_id},
success: function (obj, textstatus) {
              if(obj.status==='FAIL') {
                   console.log(obj.message);
              }
              else {
                  console.log("ok");
              }
        }
});
}
```

And in my PHP I'm giving no arguments at the moment to test a full null insert query: Edit:

```
    $consultaAcciones= "INSERT INTO acciones VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)";
$ejecAcciones = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaAcciones);
if($ejecAcciones===false){
    $response = [
'status' => 'FAIL',
        'message' => 'Accion no registrada correctamente'
    ];
}
else {
    $response = [
        'status' => 'OK',
        'message'=> 'Accion registrada'
    ];
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting "Error" in the console logs and I don't know what's wrong. Edit: No longer

Edit:
Now it doesn't display any error, it's okay, but also doesn't show my console logs for when everything's okay, also am getting a warning message:"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response"
and a log: XHR finished loading: POST "http://url...".
may it be is not correct to specify the callers of my function this way?

```
    function addListener(id,num)
{
  var target= document.getElementById(id);
  if(target){
    target.addEventListener("click",SumbitAction(num),false);

  }
  else{
    //console.log("Nel",id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting in PHP - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/296555.

Comment: If you want to see anything occurred error in your PHP code, you can try this. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1) ?>`. And you try `echo`.

Comment: Also, by default, `Ajax` receives errors through a method called `error`. You can try this. `error: function (request, status, error) { alert('Code:' + request.status + '\n' + 'message:' + request.responseText + '\n' + 'error:' + error); }`.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in the code.

First, `if(('error')) {` will always evaluate as `true`.  `'error'` is just a string, and that is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

You probably meant to compare that string against something, maybe (also removing doubled parentheses):

```
if (textstatus === 'error') {
```

Next, `textstatus` is the status of the *request*, not of your code.  It will be `error` when, for eg, there is a 404, or a 500 response from the server.  If your `INSERT` fails, the http request will still be successful, and `textstatus` will not be `error`.

You might want to check `textstatus` in an `error()` callback, if you want to add one.  But within the `success()` callback, you probably want to be checking what your *code* returned.  In this case, that is `obj`.

But looking at the PHP, it does not return anything predictable that the JS can use.  It returns nothing if the query works.  If it fails, it returns a string that begins with `Error` but then shows a MySQL error, which we won't know ahead of time, so you can't test for it in JS.

It would be better to simply return some true/false, OK/fail type msg, for eg:

```
// ... rest of your code
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaAcciones);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "FAIL";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

And in your JS:

```
if (obj === 'FAIL') {
// ... etc
```

If you actually want to pass a message back from the PHP, you should have it echo out a JSON object, eg:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaAcciones);
if ($result === false) {
    $response = [
        'status' => 'FAIL',
        // You shouldn't reveal internal details about errors
        // so don't return mysqli_error().  Maybe log it, and 
        // display something generic to your users.
        'message' => 'There was a problem'
    ];
} else {
    $response = [
        'status' => 'OK',
        'message'=> ''
    ];
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```

In your JS:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    // specify we will get a JSON response
    dataType: 'json'
    // ...
    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
        if (obj.status === 'FAIL') {
            alert(obj.message);
        } else {
            // all ok ...
        }
});
```

Comment: Am really sorry about that, did upvote but as i'm new my upvote doesn;t get recorded or smth.